# Installing Brasero removes 100+ packages and impairs internet and display manager

Tags: apt, dependencies, lightdm, brasero

I was thinking to have solved one problem with Paraview but have come across a bigger one with Brasero.

1. A few days ago [I wanted to install Paraview (amd64)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/668898/troublesome-paraview-installation-with-12-04-lts-and-not-with-14-04-lts/) in my computer (x68_64, Ubuntu 12.04 LTS) where, among others, Google-Earth and Skype used i386 libraries. This generational conflict caused apt-get to ask the removal of those older packages and attending libraries. 
   (Kudos to [Sneetsher](https://askubuntu.com/users/26246/sneetsher) for pointing me to this.)
   In the end, I managed to get **Paraview**, **Skype** and **Google Earth** properly installed and functioning after having run `apt-get -f install`, that is a general overhaul of broken dependencies. I did so on suggestion of apt-get itself.
2. However, while `apt-get -f install` was tending to its task, I noticed that some applications were disappearing from the desktop menu. I considered this natural, hence I moved on to reinstalling those. The installation of **Banshee** as first go went well (I can't recall whether using apt-get or dpkg). With **Brasero** came the fun.
3. After commanding `apt-get install brasero`, apt-get asks me to remove another large number of libraries, in the order of hundreds. Mistakenly I consider those applications *to add* and give my go ahead. At the end of this spree of autoimmune exuberance, the first evidence is that the browser cannot connect to URLs any longer -- thus the *internet connectivity* is knocked off. I then give the reboot a chance. The system goes through the POST seamlessly, then it hangs on the Ubuntu splash screen.
4. Cutting the long story short, I managed to reboot in [recovery mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode) and get to a responsive command line terminal. As the POST rolls through its checks, I can see that it fails on starting LightDM Display Manager (but maybe somewhere else that I miss).

Now the state of the play from the recovery-mode command line:

- `ping` yields a 'user unknown'
- `xterm` yields a 'display is not set'
- both `lightdm` and `gdm` yield a 'currently not installed'
- `dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` yields a 'broken or not fully installed'
- `apt-get install lightdm` gives a streak of 'failed to fetch' arguably because the internet has been cut out (checked out that the cable is in place)
- I can see the external drives though!

Hence I was thinking to circumvent the internet cut-out by saving a bridgehead of deb files on one of those drives and then running `dpkg` or `apt-get` on them from the command line. Clearly, I am not so much in favour of reinstalling the whole OS.

Does it make sense to you?
If it does, the questions are

1. Which packages and dependencies would be able to restore the internet connection?
2. Since the dependencies could easily be in the order of tens if not hundreds, is there a place where these are conveniently zipped/tarred in a single bundle? Of course I can't rely on remote fetching.
3. Say I manage to restore the internet connectivity, then I will be able to fetch the remote repositories. Which commands should I run to make sure that all 'broken pieces' are rescued and restored?
4. Why on Earth did Brasero needed to remove 100+ library packages of essential nature? This seems truly excessive to me!

Thanks for having patiently read this long post. I look forward to your answers and remarks.

**Update:** requested outputs

- [/var/lib/apt/extended_states](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12293178/)
- [/var/log/dpkg.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12293184/)

Comment: Could post the output of  `apt --installed list` or a copy of  `/var/lib/apt/extended_states` , in addition to `/var/log/dpkg.log`  to http://paste.ubuntu.com then link them to the question. They may help much any one come to answer.

Comment: `apt --installed list` yields command not found; 
[extended states](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12293178/);
[dpkg.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12293184/).
Tip for others who encounter the same kind of troubles. In the recovery mode, the /media folder was frozen (unmounted) in the situation before the problem. I had to mount a flash drive manually in order to export the files requested. Then I could redirect the output of cat into a text file in the flash drive. [This resource](http://valentino775.blogspot.nl/2009/09/how-to-manually-mount-usb-drive-in.html) has been useful to this end.

Comment: I have opened a thread with essentially the same topic on [another forum](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/231002/restore-internet-connectivity-and-graphic-desktop-manager-wiped-out-during-a-pac). I will bother to link the two post once again as either gets a satisfactory answer. Contributors to this one forum please do not hesitate to post your remarks and answers, as they will help at any rate.

Comment: It's ok, I've some things in my head. but It better if tried them when you available in chat. is it possible?

Comment: @Sneetsher Thanks for thinking along. I have two reserves on chat, that is privacy and erratic times on my part. If the forum offers a chat application that I am not aware of, only the second hurdle holds. Hope this is not too a great problem. Also it would be good that all the forum members can keep track of attempts for additional remarks or inspiration.

Comment: It's public and Ask Ubuntu provide it no concern about privacy because you are going to use same account. Do you have time now? it's using web page only no application for it AFAIK

Comment: Later, we write solution back here if we could find it. Here the link to chat room if you would like. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29452/installing-brasero-removes-100-packages-and-impairs-internet-and-display-manager

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Boot to recovery then drop to shell
2. Check the network interfaces available.

   ```
   ifconfig -a
   ```

   If you don't see IP address (`x.x.x.x`), run DHCP query to get an IP, change `eth0` with yours.

   ```
   dhclient eth0
   ```
3. Confirm connection

   ```
   ping -c3 ubuntu.com
   ```

   You should get an output similar to this:

   ```
   3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss
   ```
4. Check `dpkg` multi-arch setup

   ```
   $ dpkg --print-architecture
   amd64
   $ dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
   i386
   $ grep -ir arch /etc/dpkg/ 
   /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch:foreign-architecture i386
   ```

   If `i386` doesn't show up in 2nd & 3rd command, set it:

   ```
   echo "foreign-architecture i386" > /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch
   ```
5. Update package list

   ```
   apt-get update
   ```
6. Run

   ```
   apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
   ```
7. If still getting "unmet dependencies" message, run `aptitude`.

   ```
   aptitude
   ```

   - Press <kbd>/</kbd> to search, write `ubuntu-desktop` then <kbd>Enter</kbd>
   - Then use <kbd>n</kbd> till `ubuntu-desktop` selected, NOT `ubuntu-desktop:i386`
   - <kbd>+</kbd> to flag it for installing
8. At this point, there should be a red bar at the bottom with number `[1/..]` which indication the current solution from many other possible onces.

   - Press <kbd>e</kbd> to examine, it show what the current solution is going to do.
   - Flip through all other solutions using <kbd>.</kbd>/<kbd>,</kbd>
   - You gonna see some solutions that prefer to keep installing packages without installing `ubuntu-desktop`. Choose the one that remove less and installs `ubuntu-desktop`.

     This is not always the perfect solution, so check well then choose. Each case is specific. For current case, see [this related chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29452/installing-brasero-removes-100-packages-and-impairs-internet-and-display-manager).
   - <kbd>!</kbd> to apply then <kbd>g</kbd>, check then <kbd>g</kbd> again to confirm.
9. If every thing goes OK, reboot.
10. Then install other need tools you need, which have been removed may be.

    **Notes:** These from my personal experience, so I could be wrong. So if anyone experienced otherwise, please share it.

    - Avoid installing `.deb` binary Debian packages locally using dpkg, debi or software-center. Use repositories as possible (Ubuntu ones, PPA, Other vendors ones,...).
    - For vendors packages, look for native architecture `amd64`. In rare cases building source (if available) is easier then foreign arch.
    - Software-center, synaptic, apt-get and many other tools, for me they not fully support multiarch feature. They show only 1 solution and (except apt-get) don't show the architecture of each package.

      If you face any conflict, use `aptitude`. It shows other solutions and shows clearly all packages from all available architecture.
    - If you have to install some `i386` tools with no option for amd64. Leave them to be installed the last. If you have them already installed and you are trying to install native arch `amd64` packages then you get a conflict (basically unmet dependencies message). Let aptitude uninstalls the `i386` ones, then run clean up with `apt-get autoremove` to remove residues (auto-installed dependencies from `i386` arch). Install `amd64` packages you wanted then try installing back the removed `i386` tools.

      Why is that? If you try to install a `i386` tool, all its dependencies will be installed as `i386` too, even `amd64` ones available and can work. Later, if you try to install another `amd64` tool which have at least one overlapped dependency, you get the conflict.

      Aptitude will seem like removing the packages, but actually it is replacing some `i386` packages with the corresponding `amd64` ones.

      See this show case, [Ubuntu 14.04, problem when install gstreamer1.0-libav, unmet dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/a/568417/26246)